# Getting point geometry by clicking at the map within QGIS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, tools, pyqt5

From [QGIS 3 Plugin Tutorial](https://gis-ops.com/qgis-3-plugin-tutorial-pyqt-signal-slot-explained/) I need the example for getting a point geometry from clicking at the map.

So I have a file `point_tool.py`:

```py
from qgis.gui import QgsMapTool, QgsMapToolEmitPoint
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal

class PointTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint): 
    canvasClicked = pyqtSignal('QgsPointXY')
    
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        super(self, QgsMapTool).__init__(self, canvas)

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        point_canvas_crs = event.mapPoint()

        self.canvasClicked.emit(point_canvas_crs)
```

And in my plugin:

```py
from .point_tool import PointTool

...
def addFachdatum(self):
   self.mapTool = PointTool(self.iface.mapCanvas())
   self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(self.mapTool)
   self.mapTool.canvasClicked.connect(self.onMapClick)
    
def onMapClick(point):
   logging.warning('onMapClick: '+point.asWkt())
```

But in QGIS I get the following error:

```
2021-11-18T12:21:46     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/sschmidt/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\gga_importer\gga_importer.py", line 420, in addFachdatum
    self.mapTool = PointTool(self.iface.mapCanvas())
File "C:/Users/sschmidt/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\gga_importer\point_tool.py", line 9, in __init__
    super(self, QgsMapTool).__init__(self, canvas)
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not PointTool
```

But I don't understand the problem, because it is Python37 and `PointTool` is derived from `QgsMapToolEmitPoint` and this is `QObject`. Who can help please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
super(self, QgsMapTool).__init__(self, canvas)
```

to

```
super(QgsMapTool, self).__init__(canvas)
```